AAPF Filter group is not in widget section
as i am trying this plugin for my website AAPF Filter group is not  showing in my widget section, if i use this short code also it doesn't working [br_filters_group group_id=2661]

Nobody can help you from the details you've provided. I had to google AAPF to figure out what it was, turns out it's a paid plugin. Ask their support for help.
